# High voltage (220V) constant current LED driver using transistors

Tags: led, led-driver

This electronic circuit is a constant current LED driver using two transistors.

It is designed to work with low DC voltage like 5V or 12V.

But I'm wondering if it is possible to connect it to 220V mains voltage (311V DC after using bridge rectifier) if I used a proper high voltage transistors such as A42 or 13001 instead of low voltage BJT.

If yes, why have I never seen a commercial LED driver that used this simple method?

(My desired load is 100 3V LED in series with 100mA of current.)

[image]

Comment: There are dedicated driver ICs that integrate the current regulation (and often other things like over temperature sensing) into a single package, so it doesn't make sense to build drivers out of discrete components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i'm wondering is it possible to connect it to 220v mains voltage (311V DC after using bridge rectifier) if i used a proper high voltage transistors such as A42 or 13001 instead of low voltage BJT?

It's possible. It'll even work. Whether it's safe or not is something that'll be hard to answer.

It's also not very necessary: grid voltage is pretty reliable, so a simple series resistor would do just as well in practice (and also, would not tend to fail short as much as a transistor does, so it'd probably be safer).

Another problem is thermal stability. When the temperature of this rises, so will the current amplification of the transistors, and thus, you're building a recipe for thermal runaway and self-destruction.

> If yes so why i never seen before commercial LED driver that used this simple method?

When you have 100 LEDs in series, there will be differences in brightness among them. Little use having perfect current regulation.

Also, that's a 30W LED light. That is wall painter's floodlight bright. That's not something I would expect you to take apart on a daily basis.

Therefore: For places your simple regulator would work, a resistor would do as well, and be cheaper, and safer.

> If yes so why i never seen before commercial LED driver that used this simple method?

Also, because this is almost never a useful thing to do:

Think about it: the voltage that has to drop over this regulator (and potential series resistors you'd add) would always be your DC voltage minus your LED string voltage.

In **your** use case, you can make that drop tolerably small (11V), so that the power wasted here is tolerably small (4% of the LEDs' power). This thing is still going to get pretty hot.

When does that actually ever happen? White LEDs, due to the physics behind how they work, always have a forward voltage of around 2.8 to 3 V. So, to achieve a drop that's as tolerably low as yours, you'd need to put 100 LEDs in series.

Nobody in their right mind would produce a lamp like that! 100 LEDs in series means that your whole lamp is broken when 1 or more out of 100 LEDs is broken.

- Say, each of your LEDs have a probability of being broken of 1 in 10,000, 10⁻⁴.
- So, the probability of an LED being OK is 1-10⁴= 0.9999.
- So, the probability of 100 LEDs in a string being OK is 0.9999¹⁰⁰, that's 99%
- 1% of your lamps are broken
- Since 1% is so much that the companies selling these lamps to customers will not stock your lamps, because they will have to deal with customer complaints and their image will suffer, you now have to test every single lamp before you ship a pallet of them. That increases the cost of your low-cost lamp by a significant factor.

Yes, that would require a switch-mode power supply. As said by others, that is often necessary, anyway, for isolation requirement reasons.

Comment: ~50-100 diodes in series is actually common in cheap lights.  That is why they make LEDs that have series junctions in one package. Saves you from having to pick and place a lot of 3V diodes to get the voltage up to whatever rectified mains is in your country. I assume they test the series junctions at the package level before pick and place to get the failure rate tolerably low.

Comment: yep, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

I looked up online and there are people who followed that same idea, but I could not find any well done testing on that, any application notes or professional-level schematics. it is definitely possible that many cheaper products do use that same idea, but usually cheaper products don't care about using constant current (or safety) that much.

One of the main problems with connecting circuits straight to the power line is that **the device will be very unsafe, and you will have to add many safety circuits to it. Still, that won't give a result as good as galvanic isolation**, having a transformer and so. Also, even circuits that have galvanic isolation have many different protection circuits to mitigate problems with voltage spikes, excessive current and other things that might break the transformer isolation and harm people in contact with it (or start a fire).

All in all, it will work, but you have to make sure to add a lot of protection and make sure that the components are within spec, so it won't be as cheap as you expected nor as cheap as cheap manufacturers want.